# возникли проблемы с кодом в С

Tags: c

возникли проблемы с кодом в С
не могу вывести цифры с помощью функции `write()`
вот код

```
 #include
 char fy(char c) {
     write(1, & c, 1);
 }
 int main(void) {
     // your code goes here
     int z = 0;
     int n = 9;
     while (z <= n) {
         fy(z);
         z++;
     }
 }
```

выходит:  несколько непонятных знаков
через `printf()` нельзя. Надо только через `write()`
в чём проблема?

и как можно исправить?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Всё верно, Вы приводите обычные целочисленные значения к символам и получаете символы с кодом от 0 до 9, чтобы число правильно превратить в символ нужно добавить код символа '0' к числу.

```
char fy(char c) {
  с+='0';
  write(1, &c, 1);
}
```

Comment: aah
ASCII...
spasibo

Comment: @Dumitru Strelet Спасибо не булькает и в карман не положишь. Если данный ответ Вас удовлетворил, то отметьте его галочкой под циферкой со стрелочками. Это и будет то самое "спасибо".

Answer (score 1):

Вообще-то в C не припоминаю такой функции.
Есть `fwrite`.

Вопрос в том, что, в каком виде и куда вы хотите вывести.

Если отдельный символ в консоль -

```
fwrite(&c,sizeof(c),1,stdout);
```

Но если вы хотите выводить **числа** от 0 до 9 как **символы**, то их надо преобразовать -

```
char с = z + '0';
```

Очевидно, что это работает только для чисел от 0 до 9.

Если это не то, что вам требуется - уточните свой вопрос.

Comment: Есть такая функция, из древних, пишет в file handle.

Comment: @VladD Как минимум, ни в справочнике *C in a Nutshell*, ни в http://en.cppreference.com/w/ не описана...

Comment: Вот оно: http://linux.die.net/man/2/write (может быть, это POSIX-стандарт?)